# Regex to enforce a specific pattern

Tags: regex, regex-group

I want to validate a string which should follow a specific defined pattern.

Rule are

- it should starts with any of this three words 'Dev', 'Tweak' or 'Feature'
- then should have a space hyphen and space i.e., `-`
- and three or word followed by a period. (*also it can have URL or '#' or punctuators*)

[image: rules img]

So I have written a regex like this, but some how it is not working

```
^((Tweak|Dev|Feature)(\s-\s)(\w{3,})(\.))$
```

Here is the regex playground URL: https://regex101.com/r/136LCG/1

The regex should match following strings

1. Tweak - this should be correct.
2. Feature - my feature having a
   special character as #123.
3. Dev - this should also work
   https://regex101.com/
4. Dev - this is my message. Ref projectname#123.
5. Dev - my message having long sentence, with additional punctuators.

Comment: Try `^(?:Tweak|Dev|Feature)\s+-(?:\s+(?:#?\w+|http\S*)){3,}\.?$`, see https://regex101.com/r/T3OyKK/1

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Quite a bit more complex than the original one.  This would be a good answer if it included an explanation about why the original regex doesn't work.

Comment: OP's sample data is currently too unclear to tell if that would be a working pattern. It would not force a trailing dot, even if an URL is not present (which is the only sample OP provided that seems to be allowed without a dot).

Comment: What do you mean "it doesn't work"? Be more specific. What matches and what doesn't?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: excellent your regex is working, as expected. I missed one point so I have updated my question and added #4 and #5. Also pls add it an answer so that I can accept it. I have also updated the regex101 link

Comment: @RaunakGupta This sounds as if you wanted something like `^(?:Tweak|Dev|Feature)\s+-(?: +\S+){3,}$`. See https://regex101.com/r/136LCG/2. Before posting, I need to understand what exactly you are looking for, that is why I am asking about this using potential solutions in the comments.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Actually I am writing a pre-commit hook to validate a commit message is in the correct format or not. So you given regex is working as expected. Do you know how to make it work for Bash which uses POSIX ERE regex engine? Otherwise you can post your answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
^(?:Tweak|Dev|Feature)\s+-(?:\s+(?:#?\w+|http\S*)){3,}\.?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/T3OyKK/1). *Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:Tweak|Dev|Feature)` - one of three words
- `\s+` - one or more whitespaces
- `-` - a hyphen
- `(?:\s+(?:#?\w+|http\S*)){3,}` - three or more repetitions of

  - `\s+` - one or more whitespaces
  - `(?:#?\w+|http\S*)` - either of

    - `#?\w+` - an optional `#` char and then one or more letters, digits or underscores
    - `|` - or
    - `http\S*` - `http` and then zero or more non-whitespaces
- `\.?` - an optional `.`
- `$` - end of string.

**NOTE**: POSIX ERE does not allow using non-capturing groups, and depending on where you are using it, it might not be possible to use `\s` and `\w` shorthannd character classes. So, in POSIX ERE, the regex will look like

```
^(Tweak|Dev|Feature)[[:space:]]+-([[:space:]]+(#?[[:alnum:]_]+|http[^[:space:]]*)){3,}\.?$
```

*Details*:

- All non-capturing groups are replaced with capturing ones, `(?:...)` with `(...)`
- `\s` turned into `[[:space:]]`
- `\S` turned into `[^[:space:]]`
- `\w` turned into `[[:alnum:]_]`

Comment: Awesome, you are true wiz. Only two sentence are not working, which is num 4 and 5 given in my above question, but I can figure it now, as I have got something to work with. Thank you :)

Comment: @RaunakGupta If you know the exact requirements for Strings 4 and 5, I can help. For the time being, I can only suggest `^(?:Tweak|Dev|Feature)\s+-(?: +\S+){3,}$` as in [my comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71663123/regex-to-enforce-a-specific-pattern/71682120?noredirect=1#comment126668285_71663123).